# Is there a simple way to tell if a StackTraceElement is not from your source code?

Tags: java, io

Here's an example app, throwing an error at `Foo.main()`:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            for (StackTraceElement elem : e.getStackTrace())
                System.out.println(elem);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Foo.main(Foo.java:5)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Let's say I don't really care about the last five `StackTraceElement` objects.

Is there an easy way to filter out the ones that aren't being compiled in my project?

Comment: The package names ought to be enough to tell what's yours and what is from 3rd parties.  What else are you missing?

Comment: @Joseph Nields :  No.  Your project should have top level package.  (com.company.. or net.projectname.. )  You then check only the package name part.

Comment: @Jayan, that's a simple and easy answer that only needs a regex. Would you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extracting from comments(duffymo's and mine)

1. Pick a unique [top-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) package name.  Example will be
   `com.yourcompany` or `com.productname`... etc
2. In the exception handling routine, check if the package starts with 
   your pattern.